# How to have just one row like that?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I would like to implement a simple? table view like that with just one row with a textfield (left picture) :

[image]
[image]

But when I implement (programmatically) a table view controller with 1 section and just 1 row (with my custom cell containing just a uitextfield) I have this ugly thing (right picture).

What should I do ? I am missing something with the rows and sections ? (I would like not to use storyboards).

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Try setting up your table view with grouped style.

Comment: Why don't you just use plain a UIView for the background white container, a UITextField for text entry and padding and finally a UIButton to cancel/clear the text field ?

Comment: @rmaddy ok thank you very much ! Shoud I delete this too simple question ?

Comment: You can't delete a question that has an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok sorry for being maybe unclear in my question and asking a too simple question for many but, if that can help, I solved the problem with the rdmaddy help, writing simply :

```
MyTableViewController *vc = [[MyTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

Answer (score 0):

use tabelview delegation methods

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 1;
}
```

from utilities (right side)  from attribute inspector set sperator to single line 
or

```
self.routineTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
```

and set tabel view background to be clear and then set uiview (tabelview container ) background to be gray

Comment: This is not at all what is being asked about. The OP already has one row. The problem is the wrong table view style (plain instead of grouped).

Comment: Ok sorry for being maybe unclear in my question. I solved the problem my rdmaddy help, using simply MyTableViewController *vc = [[MyTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];